# Can you index columns in all tables in database that have the same column name?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 80 tables, and unfortunately I never bothered building relationships between tables.

I am now starting to build relationships as i've just learned about them, but have a question..

In about 63 tables i have a column called 'UserID', i was wondering is it possible to add an index to all columns with this name, automatically on all the tables without having to do it manually one by one?

Comment: Yes and no. There is no syntax to create such indexes from one statement, but you can query `information_schema.columns` selecting something like `CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' etc...) AS alterQ` to generate a list of the ALTER statements needed and then run those as a script.